# SVN invalid repository url

Tags: svn

My working copy seems to keep getting corrupted...I keep having to re-check out to fix.
I am still able to commit, but not able to update.
An svn info command points to the right repository, but if I run svn status -u, it reports svn: Illegal repository URL ''

As far as I can tell, the .svn/entries file looks correct

Comment: Hi Jeremy. If this were a problem with your SVN Repository we could probably help, but as it's a problem with your Working Copy I'm not sure how much help we'll be able to give. If there's a better site for your question, we will migrate it there soon.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out.

I originally had checked in a directory, then after checking out, I removed the directory and symlinked that directory to another directory in another project.

Comment: Feel free to mark this answer as accepted. It's perfectly fine to accept your own answers if the answer the original question.